# Handling TreeStores in Python/GTK

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am trying to write a TreeStore in python/GTK with each parent corresponding to all loaded file names ("mol_name"), and children from each parent specifying none, one or more components of the corresponding loaded file ("chain").

I would like 3 column window with the first column listing the name of each file loaded, the second being a checkbutton which toggles whether the resulting operation is applied to that file, and the third being a combobox which lists none, one or more possible components of the associated loaded file which can be selected to further refine how the operation is applied.

Below is the code I have so far. Any help or guidance in getting this to work would be greatly appreciated:

```
for imol in molecule_number_list():
    combobox_name = molecule_name(imol)
    combobox.append_text(combobox_name)
combobox.connect('changed', sel_ref_mol)
box1_vbox.pack_start(combobox, False, False)

window = gtk.Window()
window.set_default_size(200, 200)

treestore = gtk.TreeStore(str, bool)
for imol in molecule_number_list():
    mol_name = molecule_name(imol)
    piter = treestore.append(None, [mol_name, True])
    for chain in chain_ids(imol):
        treestore.append(piter, [chain, True])

treeview = gtk.TreeView(treestore)
column_text = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Text")
column_toggle = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Toggle")
column_combo = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Combo")
treeview.append_column(column_text)
treeview.append_column(column_toggle)
treeview.append_column(column_combo)

cellrenderer_text = gtk.CellRendererText()
column_text.pack_start(cellrenderer_text, False)
column_text.add_attribute(cellrenderer_text, "text", 0)

cellrenderer_toggle = gtk.CellRendererToggle()
column_toggle.pack_start(cellrenderer_toggle, True)
column_toggle.add_attribute(cellrenderer_toggle, "active", 1)

cellrenderer_combo = gtk.CellRendererCombo()
cellrenderer_combo.set_property("editable", True)
cellrenderer_combo.set_property("model", treestore)
cellrenderer_combo.set_property("text-column", 0)
column_combo.pack_start(cellrenderer_combo, False)
column_combo.add_attribute(cellrenderer_combo, "text", 2)
```

Comment: Btw which import are you using, `import gtk` or `from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk` ? The former is older import (for GTK2, which is being phased out), gi.repository imports GTK3.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you haven't added your treeview to your window or shown the treeview/window, the code looks fine to me at first glance. Can you be more specific about what is failing and/or what aspect of this problem you're having trouble with?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm using a molecular graphics program that runs in Windows and comes packaged with Python, allowing execution of user python scripts. The sample scripts that comes with the software use "import gtk".

Comment: Basically, I'd like to use the combobox to display only the children of each parent - not a two tiered parent->children selection process.

Comment: "import gtk" is the older pygtk import. Can you check and see if a later version supports GTK3?